# Convert date to zero based number, account for weekend gap

Tags: java, date

I am looking for a way to convert a date to a number. In my program, I am taking stock market data and filling an ArrayList with GregorianCalendar types.

What I want is an array of integers that account for the weekend gap, eg

```
[2015-11-02, 2015-11-03, 2015-11-04, 2015-11-05, 2015-11-06, 2015-11-09, 2015-11-10]
```

would be

```
[0,1,2,3,4,7,8]
```

I know in python this can be done with matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num, but can't find a way in Java. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can get the day part from the minimum date and keep it as a reference number. Then go through each of the dates and subtract each day value by this reference number and you will get the desired array.

Comment: So you're looking for the number days from the anchor date to any of the other dates. Use Java 8s Time API OR JodaTime

Comment: I like the look of JodaTime, could you expand on your answer a little (Sorry, I'm very new to Java) - is it the interval feature I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **[`LocalDate#toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--)** and to make a substraction to get the difference between both dates.

The method returns a `long` but I casted it into an `int` since we'll never use the capacity of a the `long` variable.

---

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2015, 01, 01);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2015, 01, 15);
    System.out.println(difference(date1,date2)); // Prints 14 
}

public static int difference(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2){
    return (int) (d2.toEpochDay() - d1.toEpochDay());
}
```